# javascript - Extract items from array and add with a new key to a new array of a specific length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array of images:

```
const imageArray = Object.entries(profileData.images)

//imageArray  = ["0": "http://imagelink1", "1" : "http://imagelink2"]
```

I am setting an initial state of images array to

```
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState([
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
  ])
```

Expected initial state is

```
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState([
    { image: 'http://imagelink1' },
    { image: 'http://imagelink2' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
    { image: '' },
  ])
```

How to get values from first array and construct this new array of length 6?

Comment: `Object.entries()` returns a 2d array of the form `[[key1, val1], ...]`, not too clear on how your `imageArray` is a 1d array of strings. Are you sure `imageArray` is what you're saying it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new array with [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from), and then use the index from your array that you're creating to grab the image from `imageArray`. If the index doesn't exist in your `imageArray` you can take a default of `""` using the [nullish coalescing `??`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing) operator:

```js
const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(() => 
  Array.from({length: 6}, (_, i) => ({image: imageArray[i] ?? ""}))
)
```

Above I'm passing a function into `useState()` so that the array is only constructed on the initial mount of your component and not on every rerender (it's useless after the first render anyway, so no need to reconstruct it)

Answer (score 1):

So you can use `Array` constructor with `n` number of elements, and use `fill` to fill the items with a value, and then `map` with each item with its' corresponding index in `imageArray`

```
  const [imageUrl, setImageUrl] = useState(Array(6).fill(undefined).map((item, index) => ({ image: imageArray[index] ?? '' })))
```

Comment: Great - How to make sure there are 6 elements always even if last few are empty depending on passed data in imageArray?

Comment: @Kal, you can use `slice` method, to get the first 6 items even if there are more than 6, I just update the answer.

Comment: @Kal, one question do you want the first 6 URLs? or first 6 URLs are not empty strings?

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear. I always want the array length to be 6 because I am using the array to present empty placeholders for image upload if there are no pictures in all 6 tiles. So if there are 2 images the last 4 tiles will be empty with a +

Comment: @Kal, I now understood, I just update the answer.